# Aspnet Core Identity Login and register google chrome not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

In my asp net core project, identity login and register codes do not work in google chrome. IE and Edge also do not have any inconvenience. I suspect Cookie. Couldn't find any solution...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContextPool<WSContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("WSConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WSContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


            //services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 10;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 3;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            });

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                // Cookie settings
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();

                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=index}/{id?}"
                    );
            });

        }
```

As you can see in the pictures there is not any identity request post.Thank you in advance for your help...

Comment: Where is the picture ? And I could not understand the exactly `not working` means.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't upload the picture. After a few attempts I found the problem but still can not solve it.The problem can be registered with an e-mail like abc@gmail.com, but does not register with an e-mail like firstname.lastname@xxxx.xxx.xx. register httpPost method  not working. firstname.lastname@xxxx.xxx.xx does not fall to breakpoint.

Comment: @XingZou just google chrome is also happening.

Comment: I could not reproduce that, it also works well in my scaffolded Identity when I use `firstname.lastname@xxxx.xxx.xx` to register.Do you have `[EmailAddress]` attribute  for the Email property in register.cshtml.cs?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite